# Visual Studio find Code Paths/Paths of Execution

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking for a Visual Studio add on which will make the the task of finding code paths easier. Basically, I want something that will find all references of all references, of all references....

For example, I have dozens of forms and dozens of web services. I want to map which form would call what web service instead of right-clicking on the web-service and doing a find all references over and over again through several layers.

Does this tool even exist? I know of ones that will find un-used code but none that will show me execution paths.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/ I *think* this may suit your needs.

Comment: Thing's not cheap though..

Comment: ReSharper will show you execution and value paths, but I doubt it would work across service boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). It does exactly what I need it to do, generate a dependency graph, and had multiple ways to export it as well as visualize the dependencies. In addition, I found the CQLinq queries to be extremely powerful in cutting down the noise to only find the dependencies I was interested in and skipping different layers when necessary.

Comment: Here are additional explanations about the NDepend graph http://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph  and about the LINQ querying of code depencencies http://www.ndepend.com/docs/cqlinq-features#Dependencies